# Boot straight into an application without showing the desktop

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, fullscreen

How do I boot straight into an application without showing the desktop?

Essentially I would like to turn the machine on, see the grey screen with loading icon, and then see my application. The Desktop/Dock/Menubar should never be visible. (The application itself is fullscreen)

Comment: Seen may, this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open new windows in full screen by default, I don't know any way to do it in general, but there are options for it in some applications like iTerm 2, VLC, and WriteRoom.

You could also [assign a keyboard shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    reopen -- open a new default window if there are open default windows
    set w to number of windows
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"
    if number of windows is w then -- if there are no full screen windows
        perform action "AXPress" of (button 1 where subrole is "AXFullScreenButton") of window 1
    end if
end tell
activate application "Terminal" -- make Terminal frontmost
```

To automate opening a window in full screen at login, you might use a script like this:

```
set old to window 1
tell application "Terminal"
    reopen
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"
    perform action "AXPress" of (button 1 where subrole is "AXFullScreenButton") of window 1
end tell
delay 1.5
activate old
```

Comment: But this still shows the desktop whilst the script is executed. I have amended the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AppleScript using Automator.

Comment: and then what ?